# Animation for action bar show action

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using android 4.2 with appCompat of the latest version. I've implemented showing and hiding my action bar with these methods:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
actionBar.show();
```

When action bar is being hide, it does so with smooth animation gradually sliding up. However, when I show it it appears on the screen almost instantly, almost without smooth animation sliding down. Is there any way I can configure it to show smoothly as it happens with hiding it?

Comment: Have you enable this properties setShowHideAnimationEnabled() ?

Comment: This seems to be it, thanks a lot! Make it an answer so that I can accept it. And also clarify please, is `ShowHideAnimation` disabled by default?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to enable ActionBar hide/shown animation which is by deafult not enable so enable hide/shown animation using below code :

```
actionBar.setShowHideAnimationEnabled(boolean enabled);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, can you please take a look at my [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117177/action-bar-is-hidden-and-that-shown-instantly-after-that).

Answer (score 4):

Set in you layout  `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in `AppBarLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"

        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And Toggle for hide or show toolbar (ActionBar)

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {

    if (getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    } else {
        getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
}
```

Comment: By far, this is the cleanest answer.