# Action bar is hidden and that shown instantly after that

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to toggle show/hide action bar on user click on activity, so I've implemented this functionality like this in activity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.d("ACTION BAR", "triggered");

    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    if (actionBar.isShowing()) {
        actionBar.hide();
    } else {
        actionBar.show();
    }

    return true;
}
```

However, the problem is that when clicked on activity, the action bar gets hidden but then immediately is shown again. I've added logging and it seems that this method is triggered twice, why so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think dispatchTouchEvent might be called two time on touch down and up action so take one boolean flag and check this flag value before showing action bar :

```
private boolean isManuallyHideShownActionBar;

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    if(!isManuallyHideShownActionBar){
        if (actionBar.isShowing()) {
            actionBar.hide();
        } else {
            actionBar.show();
        }
        isManuallyHideShownActionBar = true;
    }else{
        isManuallyHideShownActionBar = false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks, now it's half working :). When I touch an activity, the action bar gets hidden - so OK here, but then when I touch it again, the action bar shows and then hides immediately, next touch will work OK and show the action bar. Why so? I'm also thinking that maybe I've taken the wrong approach because I need to show action bar on click but don't need to show it on longclick - can you please comments in terms of approach correctness that I'm using? How would you implement it?

Comment: Now i try to correct my code can you please check updated code ?

Comment: Yeah, it's working correct now, thanks, but as I said I think I've chosen the wrong approach from the outset. I need to identify whether it's a long click first and if it's not only then show the action bar. Any idea how to do that?